# Adding successive values in a column of a csv in R

Tags: r

I am new to coding so this is probably very basic. I was wondering how to add two successive values in a column of a csv along its entire length. Say this was my data:

`[1] 2`
`[2] 3`
`[3] 4`
`[4] 5`

I want to make a vector which contains 2+3, 3+4 and 4+5 (but obviously my real data set is much larger).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `cumsum()`:

If this is your vector:

```
vector <- 2:5
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

You would need to:

```
cumsum(vector)
[1]  2  5  9 14
```